# angularjs check authorisation on server

Tags: angularjs, http, laravel, authentication

how can i check if an user is loggedin on the server (not client side) with angularjs?

i tried:

```
userModel.getAuthStatus = function() {

       var r = $http({
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: baseUrl + 'user/auth',
            method: "POST"
        }).success(function(response) {
           // console.log(response);
            if(response.user){
                console.log('login ');
                var auth = true;
            }else{
                console.log('login is false');
                var auth =  false;
            }
            return auth;
            //$cookies.put('auth', JSON.stringify(response));
        }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
            //console.log(data, status, headers);
            //alert(data);
        });

        console.log(r);
    };
```

on my serverside i get a response like:

```
public function checkAuth(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return Response::json(array('error' => false,'user' => Auth::user()),201);
        }
        else{
            return Response::json(array('error'=>true));
        }
    }
```

i want my angular getAuthStatus() to go to the server, if the user is logged in return true. else return false.

Comment: What is the issue? Are you not receiving the POST from the client at the server?

Comment: not sending any data in your request ... that would help. When asking questions should identify what is or isn't working. You have code shown for 2 environments and no problem description

Comment: The problem is that console.log(r) give the http post object.

'code'Promise {$$state: Object}
$$state: Object
error: (fn)
success: (fn)
__proto__: Promise
catch: (callback)
constructor: Promise()
finally: (callback, progressBack)
then: (onFulfilled, onRejected, progressBack)
__proto__: Object 
'code

Comment: `r` is the promise object returned by `$http` ....  return that promise if you want to return from `getAuthStatus ()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular, i recommend you use a controller function to execute the request

```
$scope.auth = false;
$scope.verifySession = function(){
     $http.get('/auth/login')
          .success(function(data){
                if(data.auth) $scope.auth = true;
                else $scope.auth = false;
          })
          .error(function(data){
                console.log("Error: ", data);
          });
     }
$scope.verifySession();
```

In the controller if you use a `Route::controller('/auth', 'AuthController');` you coul write our controller method like this

```
public function getLogin(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return Response::json(array('error' => false,'user' => Auth::user()),201);
    }
    else{
        return Response::json(array('error'=>true));
    }
}
```